# Are struct scalar members zero-initialized when using value-initialization on a struct with a default non-trivial-constructor

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, value-initialization, zero-initialization

If I have the following struct

```
struct test
{
    char *x;
    std::string y;
};
```

And I initialize with

```
test *t = new test();
```

That should value-initialize the object and do the following based on the standard:

> if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then
> the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked, and if T
> has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;

`struct test` has a non-trivial constructor, this can be checked with:

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_constructible<test>::value, "test is not is_trivially_constructible");`)
```

Does the standard imply that my `test` object should **always** be zero-initialized in the case of value-initialization, and then **subsequently** default-initialized?

And should I be able to reliably assume that after doing `test *t = new test()` if I immediately check `t->x == nullptr`, that should be true because `char *x` (a pointer / scalar type) should get zero-initialized during value-initialization of `test`.

I ask because Coverity gives a `Type: Uninitialized pointer read (UNINIT)` warning because it reports the following if you try do something like `if (t->x)` after value-intialization:

> Assigning: "t" = "new test", which is allocated but not initialized.

Is Coverity misinterpreting the standard as "value-initialization if trivial constructor **OR** default-initialization if non-trivial constructor"? If I remove the `std::string y;` member so that `test` has a trivial-default-constructor, Coverity no longer has a warning and assumes the `char *x` member is zero-initialized.

For what it's worth, I'm just using `g++ -O3 -std=c++17` to compile and I have not been able to create an actual scenario where zero-intialization doesn't happen for my `test` object.

Comment: The warning is correct for C++98, but not any later revisions. Maybe there is a setting to ignore C++98-only issues? Also the message is suspect. It doesn't include the `()` initializer which makes all the difference here. (That it makes all the difference seems very fragile btw. It could be made much safer without losing anything by just writing `char *x{};` in the class definition.)

Comment: Don't use new when you don't have to. If you need a pointer to leverage (dynamic) polymorphism use std::make_unique. Otherwhise work with instances and references

Comment: Here is a nice article on the topic by [Sy Brand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496161/tartanllama) with telling title [Initialization in C++ is bonkers](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/initialization-is-bonkers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is not correct for modern C++(including C++17) as explained below.

> should I be able to reliably assume that after doing `test *t = new test();` if I immediately check `t->x == nullptr`, that should be true because `char *x` (a pointer / scalar type) should get zero-initialized during value-initialization of test.

Yes, it is guaranteed by the standard that `x` is zero-initialized and hence the check `t->x == nullptr` must evaluate to `true`. This can be seen from [dcl.init#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#6) which states:

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, its padding bits are initialized to zero bits and **each non-static data member**, each non-virtual base class subobject, and, if the object is not a base class subobject, each virtual base class subobject **is zero-initialized**;

(emphasis mine)